Is there a way to reduce, customize youtube user thumbnail size on the YouTube home page or subscription feed?
Having issues with YouTube forcing a crazy huge thumbnail display size on the web browser.
This display shows 2, 3 or 4 videos in width, even if on a very high res display.
Google seems to have zero desire to allow the user to specify thier preference on this.
I am hoping for a custom style that fixes the sizing of the displayed thumbnails to make scanning the videos easier (or similar to the old style).


Why wasn't this moved to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/?

Note: I am posting this simply because I could not find any other way to get YouTube to fix this issue and wanted others to be able to benefit from it.

Example Using StyleBot (or use any other User Style Extension or mechanizm) The below small block of CSS allows you to specify the Thumbnail display size and return some normalness to your video browsing experience (Discovered after a few hours of fighting with the page source).
#thumbnail, #details, ytd-rich-item-renderer, ytd-rich-item-renderer div {
   max-width: 300px !important;
   max-height: 250px !important;
}

Adjust the width and height above to fix the display to your desired size.


